# I can't establish a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm studying VB.net with SQL Server, and I'm doing [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odrntJn2o98). But when I run the program, an error shows. I already tried to solve it myself and saw some remedy in the comment section on YouTube, but I can't resolve it myself.

[image: pics]

Comment: It is _JORDAN-PC_

Comment: @Steve  hey steve, it works like a magic! thank you very much. can you explain to me, what really happens?

Comment: @jrdn128 You may have better luck with questions like this at [superuser @ SE](http://superuser.com), because it is not related to programming, but more to administration, as connectivity issue is most probably caused by name resolution (check your `Server=` clause to contain a DNS name rather than NetBIOS one).

Comment: If you look at the object explorer window it is clear that when you installed SQL Server you have installed it on a PC named JORDAN-PC not on a PC named JORDANPC (or you have someway managed to change the name of the default Instace). The name of the host pc (being it a server or your local machine) is used for your Data Source.

Comment: @Steve thank mate . i understand now very. so its about finding the right name of my PC since it is a localhost, is there anyway to say thank you here? up vote or commend

Comment: Your thanks are appreciated. This is just a typo and there is no sense to write an answer to fix it. See you again on SO

Answer (score 0):

Enable sql browser by pressing windows +R  and type services.msc .Make sure sql server is running and also enable remote connection to MS sql instance